# I have a JS bug when launching a wizard from an action in Odoo 16

Tags: javascript, odoo

The proccess to produce this error is like that: in the tree view I select a record, added an action button when clicked it open a wizard that takes the selected record and when I click on the line of this record this error message came in:

[image]

This is [a video to see the problem](https://youtu.be/w-xPtN-zwgY) (it’s a custom module).

In the beginning, I thought the bug was because Odoo 16 is not stable yet so I waited and tested every new release but nothing changed.

edit: I found  out that the tree mode view of the many2many field (lines) in wizard form view is the reason of that JS error here is the code of wizard and its view:

```
from odoo import models, fields

class LockPlannedMoney(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'lock.planned.money'
    _description = 'Verrouillage de ligne de trésorerie'

    lines = fields.Many2many('planned.money', string='Lignes')

    def confirm_date(self):
        for line in self.lines:
            line.lock_button()
```

and  this is the form view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <!--     ================ view  form  peridique ==============    -->
        <record id="lock_planned_money_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">lock.planned.money.view</field>
            <field name="model">lock.planned.money</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <field name="lines" widget="one2many" mode="tree" nolabel="1" readonly="0">
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                            <field name="label" readonly="1" />
                            <field name="partner_id" readonly="1" />
                            <field name="type_id" readonly="1" />
                            <field name="date" readonly="1" />
                            <field name="predicted_date" readonly="1" />
                            <field name="due_date" />
                            <field name="lock_status" string=" " />
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="confirm_date" string="Confirmer" type="object" class="oe_highlight" />
                        <button special="cancel" string="Annuler" />
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- Action de Verrouillage-->
        <record id="lock_button_action_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Vérrouiller</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">lock.planned.money</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="lock_planned_money_form_view" />
            <field name="context">{'default_lines': active_ids}</field>
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="eloapps_cash_flow_forecast.model_planned_money" />
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Please review your custom module code.

Comment: Can you add example code? JS errors are not that good to even guess what's the problem. You mentioned trying out with some odoo releases. How did you set up the "next" test: by using your old database or by creating a new one with the newer odoo release.

Comment: `.find` applies to an array. The error message you're getting suggests that `this.options` is either undefined or not an array. I would `console.log(this.options)` to see what it contains. Failing that, some code will be required for anyone to assist you! :)

Comment: @CZoellner i have added the code check out my edit tnx in advance

Comment: Have you tried without using widget `one2many`?